# Recuperar audio do GetUserMedia para gravar

Tags: javascript, html, android, getusermedia

Bom dia pessoal,

eu já fiz tratamento para gravar áudio com o GetUserMedia. Usei como base esse exemplo (https://mdn.github.io/web-dictaphone/), tem o mesmo código do js.

O problema é que o framework que uso exige um arquivo físico (pode colocar mais se quiser) para enviar ao servidor. Eu não encontrei outra forma no GetUserMedia pra fazer isso porque o áudio só está na memória e não é interessante gerar arquivo no navegador.

Eu uso o sistema no Android também.

Alguém tem ideia de como fazer esse tratamento pra enviar o áudio ao servidor?

Comment: Bom.. acabei resolvendo criando um file em memória e repassando ao framework. Não foi necessário arquivo físico.